# Google play 64 bits error despite apk is provided with all native libraries in 64 and 32 bits

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit

I'm submitting an apk to goole play that seems perfectly 64 bits compliant, it has all native libraries provided in 32 bits and 64 bits. But I still get this error when trying to deploy the apk in the gogole play console :

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, 
>   but they only have 32-bit native code: 2.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use  the Android
>   App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device
>   architecture receives  only the native code that it needs.  This
>   avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More

Here is a screenshot of native libraries in the apk :

[image]

This apk seems to be perfectly 64 bits compliant to me, I'm really stuck on this, any help or idea very appreciated.

[edit 2019 11 14] After comment from following comment from Robert, I checked all 10 .so libraries with the tool arm-linux-androideabi-readelf provided by the ndk.

I used these 2 commands :

```
arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -h armeabi-v7a/*
```

which outputs 10 ELF headers looking like this :

```
File: armeabi-v7a/libVuforia.so
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          17252004 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 27
```

And :

```
arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -h arm64-v8a/*
```

which outputs 10 ELF headers looking like this :

```
File: arm64-v8a/libVuforia.so
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x10f3a0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          27138992 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         26
  Section header string table index: 25
```

That seems to confirm that the 10 .so libraries are correctly provided in 32 and 64 bits. Still stuck, any help very appreciated.

Comment: Unzip the APK and check each .so file for the ABI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620667 May be there is a armv7 abi file in the armv8a abi folder?

Comment: Thx for the idea, just checked all my .so with the tool arm-linux-androideabi-readelf and they all use the cpu architecture they're supposed to use : /

Comment: Then everything should be fine according to the [Google Play 64-bit requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit). Or do you have libs for other architectures not visible in the screen shot?

Comment: Actually we tried several combinations, we submitted only with arm 32/64, then we tried with both arm and x86, but nothing works. We tried with multiple apks (one for each architecture), and on universal apk embedding all architectures. We've opened a ticket because that seems a weird problem. I've submitted very similar apps without any problems before...

Comment: Same problem here, did you get some update for your ticket ?

Comment: @Jerome, see accepted answer, it was my problem too, an old retained apk in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (for my case - maybe the same as yours)

In the Dev console, I had an old apk which was set as "retained" (in 32bits, for old Android devices : 14+ to 19).
Disabling it allowed me to successfully deploy my new bundle.

Hope it can help.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly that. Thanks.