# Add NEON to Android.mk but get "Invalid address 0xe76a4080 passed to free: value not allocated"

Tags: android, neon

I tried to run project on Android and plan to add NEON code in the future. I don't have error when I run my regular code but when I add NEON flags in Android.mk, without changing any other code, when I got error

```
Invalid address 0xe76a4080 passed to free: value not allocated
```

The way I add NEON flag is referred from [Android build system, NEON and non-NEON builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679363/android-build-system-neon-and-non-neon-builds)

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -Werror -O3 -march=armv7-a
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS   := -std=c++11
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -llog 
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -L./android_Release/ship -lcnnRPC
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -march=armv7
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Solved. Some asm code messed up the memory.