# Android ndk 8b Cannot load library

Tags: android, android-ndk

Upgrading to ndk 8b I receiving some crash report (most of them are Galaxy SII with Android 4.03)

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1286]: 1836 cannot locate '__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'...
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
at com.iuculano.fplayer.SDLActivity.void onCreate(android.os.Bundle)(SourceFile:324)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The exception is caused by a simple `System.loadLibrary("main");`

What does it mean? `cannot locate '__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'`

Comment: please run your ndk-build with V=1 and post the command line for link step

Comment: Have you had any problem with devices with OS != 4.0.3?

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, where i am loading SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this) and it throws me about exception. Which works fine in Android 4.2 and higher, but not working in HTC one V device having v4.0.3, please help!!

Answer (score 6):

The `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi` is a helper which does an indexed jump on a densely packed switch table; quickly implements the switch. You have two options: avoid it or link with it.

If you increase an optimization level (by using `-O3`) you might not need this symbol.  Also, changing the CPU may help as well as using `thumb2` instructions.  Compiling with the `-ffreestanding` option may also avoid this symbol.  If you have control over the switch statement, you can replace it with an array of function pointers.

This routine is inside *libgcc*.  You can statically link *libgcc*.  Somewhere in the Android SDK/compiler, there must be a `libgcc.a`.   Link with `libgcc.a`, using `-L` and `-l` or use `-static-libgcc` linker option to get the code (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

**Edit:**  If you aren't compiling anything, then you can find `libgcc.so` on your system.  It might be in `/lib` or `/usr/lib` or perhaps some place weird for Android devices.  Adding the directory where the `libgcc.so` is located to the environment variable **`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`** could also fix the problem.  It maybe unfortunate that Samsung released incompatible binaries and you have no way to fix the issue if you aren't compiling your own code.  The correct `libgcc.so` maybe inside something like `/usr/lib/thumb` for multi-lib distributions.  I don't know much about the Davlik stuff, but the Android JVM might not pointing to the right set of libraries when it runs.

Comment: This hasn't solved the problem for me yet, but it's good information nonetheless...

Comment: Unfortunately, NDK does not export `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi` in any of its libraries.

Comment: NDK by itself is probably using 'bionic'; a google libc, so libgcc.so is probably not the issue, but some 'bionic' library version which doesn't include it, probably you would have to build with an older NDK to not have the symbol.  I think the function will be the same in 'bionic' as glibc; a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Are you compiling for armv7? If you're not, try compiling for armv7.

Comment: I'm compiling also for armv7, and I really don't understand why you wrote about the Necessitas Qt Creator

Comment: Because I made a mistake, sorry :-) I confused the question with another one in which Qt Creator was used. Anyway, I had the same exact issue when trying to load a library compiled for armv5 on a armv7 device. Compiling for armv5 made it work perfectly, so I didn't investigate further, but I thought it might help.

Answer (score 1):

[Producing optimised NDK code for multiple architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089783/producing-optimised-ndk-code-for-multiple-architectures)

read about 'arm' vs 'thumb' in the accepted answer in the above link.

then, remove your config instructions to build for thumb and verify that you are building for arm...

OR...

ill make a wild guess ... its the library order you have in the linker statement in your 'Android.mk'

try the google forum for ndk ... searching for 'cannot locate symbol'...

Really desperate?

see 'Runtime errors' section [here](http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/debuggingtips_C++.html)